# Memory efficient way to create a set from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I have a list of lists, in which each inner-list is a tokenized text, so its length is the number of words in the text.

```
corpus = [['this', 'is', 'text', 'one'], ['this', 'is', 'text', 'two']]
```

Now, I want to create a set that contains all unique tokens from the corpus. For the above example, the desired output would be:

```
{'this', 'is', 'text', 'one', 'two}
```

Currently, I have:

```
all_texts_list = list(chain(*corpus))
vocabulary = set(all_texts_list)
```

But this seems a memory-inefficient way of doing it.

Is there a more efficient way to obtain this set?

---

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514179/set-of-list-of-lists-in-python). However, there they want to find the set of unique lists and not the set of unique elements from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop with set `update` operation.

```
vocabulary = set()

for tokens in corpus:
    vocabulary.update(tokens)
```

**Output:**

```
{'this', 'one', 'text', 'two', 'is'}
```