# add vs update in set operations in python

Tags: python, set

What is the difference between add and update operations in python if i just want to add a single value to the set.

```
a = set()
a.update([1]) #works
a.add(1) #works
a.update([1,2])#works
a.add([1,2])#fails
```

Can someone explain why is this so.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? For `a.update(1)` I expect `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, and got it for both versions I tried.

Comment: @thefoutheye, your edit changed the question quite a bit

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OP has mentioned that `#fails` and `#works`. I just included the actual error messages. Hope that is fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye, originally the OP had said `a.update(1)` worked

Comment: @PadraicCunningham We both know that it won't work. Can we agree that its just a copy/paste mistake? If not, please feel free to revert my revision :)

Comment: @thefourtheye. well I think if there were a copy paste error it would have been `a.update(1)` was supposed to be `a.update([1])` which would make more sense.

Comment: @thefoureye yes it was a copy paste error on my end

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There.. I reverted the changes. I really thought it would make more sense to the readers if they saw the actual error messages as well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you undo the revert pls. It was a copy paste error on my end.

Comment: @aceminer, you can edit your question. Is it supposed to be `update([1])` or `update(1)# fails`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I presumed it was maybe meant to have been `update([1])` which meant you could add a single element with update but not add multiple elements with  add.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh yeah... That makes more sense.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**[`set.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.add)**

`set.add` adds an individual element to the set. So,

```
>>> a = set()
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([1])
```

works, but it cannot work with an iterable, unless it is hashable. That is  the reason why `a.add([1, 2])` fails.

```
>>> a.add([1, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Here, `[1, 2]` is treated as the element being added to the set and as the error message says, [a list cannot be hashed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23268899/1903116) but all the elements of a set are expected to be hashables. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set),

> Return a new `set` or `frozenset` object whose elements are taken from iterable. The elements of a set must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable).

**[`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.update)**

In case of [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.update), you can pass multiple iterables to it and it will iterate all iterables and will include the individual elements in the set. *Remember:* It can accept only iterables. That is why you are getting an error when you try to update it with `1`

```
>>> a.update(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

But, the following would work because the list `[1]` is iterated and the elements of the list are added to the set.

```
>>> a.update([1])
>>> a
set([1])
```

`set.update` is basically an equivalent of in-place set union operation. Consider the following cases

```
>>> set([1, 2]) | set([3, 4]) | set([1, 3])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> set([1, 2]) | set(range(3, 5)) | set(i for i in range(1, 5) if i % 2 == 1)
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Here, we explicitly convert all the iterables to sets and then we find the union. There are multiple intermediate sets and unions. In this case, `set.update` serves as a good helper function. Since it accepts any iterable, you can simply do

```
>>> a.update([1, 2], range(3, 5), (i for i in range(1, 5) if i % 2 == 1))
>>> a
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: In case you want to update my_set from the sets in an iterable of iterables you must use `my_set.update(*[s for s in iterable])`, passing a generator in as in  `my_set.update(s for s in iterable)` will update the set with the elements of the iterable and will blow if those elements are not hashable

Answer (score 27):

`add` is faster for a single element because it is exactly for that purpose, adding a single element:

```
In [5]: timeit a.update([1])
10000000 loops, best of 3: 191 ns per loop

In [6]: timeit a.add(1) 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 69.9 ns per loop
```

`update`  expects an iterable or iterables so  if you have a single hashable element to add then use `add` if you have an iterable or iterables of hashable elements to add use `update`.

> s.add(x)       add element x to set s
>
> s.update(t)    s |= t  return set s with elements added from t

Comment: While this is probably obvious, it should be noted that `update` is much faster for adding lots of elements at once: `timeit a.update( range(10000) ) # => 1000 loops, best of 3: 431 µs per loop`, meanwhile `timeit for i in range(10000): a.add(i) # => 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop`

Answer (score 12):

`add` adds an element, `update` "adds" another iterable `set`, `list` or `tuple`, for example:

```
In [2]: my_set = {1,2,3}

In [3]: my_set.add(5)

In [4]: my_set
Out[4]: set([1, 2, 3, 5])

In [5]: my_set.update({6,7})

In [6]: my_set
Out[6]: set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Just a note that this notation is fairly recent. Python 2.7  and Python 3.1, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31072911/1143274

Answer (score 5):

`.add()` is intended for a single `element`, while `.update()` is for the introduction of other sets.

*From help():*

```
add(...)
    Add an element to a set.

    This has no effect if the element is already present.


update(...)
    Update a set with the union of itself and others.
```

Answer (score 3):

`add` only accepts a hashable type. A list is not hashable.

Answer (score 3):

`a.update(1)` in your code won't work. `add` accepts an element and put it in the set if it is not already there but `update` takes an iterable and makes a unions of the set with that iterable. It's kind of like `append` and `extend` for the lists.

Answer (score 1):

I guess no one mentioned about the good resource from Hackerrank. I'd like to paste how Hackerrank mentions the difference between update and add for set in python.

Sets are unordered bag of unique values. A single set contains values of any immutable data type.

CREATING SET

```
myset = {1, 2} # Directly assigning values to a set

myset = set() # Initializing a set

myset = set(['a', 'b']) # Creating a set from a list

print(myset)  ===> {'a', 'b'}
```

**MODIFYING SET - add() and update()**

```
myset.add('c')

myset  ===>{'a', 'c', 'b'}

myset.add('a') # As 'a' already exists in the set, nothing happens

myset.add((5, 4))

print(myset) ===> {'a', 'c', 'b', (5, 4)} 


myset.update([1, 2, 3, 4]) # update() only works for iterable objects

print(myset) ===> {'a', 1, 'c', 'b', 4, 2, (5, 4), 3}

myset.update({1, 7, 8})

print(myset) ===>{'a', 1, 'c', 'b', 4, 7, 8, 2, (5, 4), 3}

myset.update({1, 6}, [5, 13])

print(myset) ===> {'a', 1, 'c', 'b', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, (5, 4), 13, 3}
```

Hope it helps. For more details on Hackerrank, [here is the link.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sets)

Answer (score 0):

add method directly adds elements to the set while the update method converts first argument into set then it adds
the list is hashable therefore we cannot add a hashable list to unhashable set.

Answer (score 0):

We use `add()` method to add single value to a set.

We use `update()` method to add sequence values to a set.

Here Sequences are any iterables including `list`,`tuple`,`string`,`dict` etc.

Comment: There is not really any additional values regarding to the already existing answers.